# SQL: Query a List within a List XML

Tags: sql, xml, xpath

I'm trying to query some XML in SQL Server but am having difficulties:

Here is some sample XML:

```
<BaseReport>
  <Parties>
    <Party>
     <SubjectType>
      <ListItem Name="SubjectType1Name" />
      <ListItem Name="SubjectType2Name" />
     </SubjectType>
    </Party>
    <Party>
      <SubjectType>
       <ListItem Name="SubjectType1Name" />
       <ListItem Name="SubjectType2Name" />
     </SubjectType>
    </Party>
  </Parties>
</BaseReport>
```

My goal is to extract the Subject Type name from my xml.  I'm not sure how to query the list within a list though.  I want to grab the first Party's first subject type.  I've tried the following to no avail:

```
 SELECT myXML.value('(/BaseReport/Parties/Party/SubjectType/@Name)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Name_Type
 FROM MyTable
```

And it returns all nulls (aka my query is wrong).  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

> I want to grab the first Party's first
>   subject type

So, the correct XPath should be:

```
/BaseReport/Parties/Party[1]/SubjectType/ListItem[1]/@Name
```